# Subclass is not returned to controller from view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

The structure is:

```
public class SchoolsInformationFooViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Параметры отчета")]
    public Options options { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Секции строк")]
    public IEnumerable<box> boxes { get; set; }

}

public class Options
{
    [Display(Name = "Период")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller - send:

```
// GET: SchoolsInformation
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     Options options = new Options { date = DateTime.Today };
     SchoolsInformationFooViewModel model = new SchoolsInformationFooViewModel { options = options };
     return View(model);         
 }
```

Controller-receipt:

```
// POST: SchoolsInformation
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "date")] Options options) 
{
    // Here options.date == null
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.options.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.options.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.options.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Html:

```html
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="Поле Период должно содержать дату." data-val-required="Требуется поле Период." id="options_date" name="options.date" type="datetime" value="23.08.2021 0:00:00">
```

The date is passed to the view successfully. But an empty class is returned - all properties are empty (null). Why this is so - I cannot understand. I tried adding prefixes to the bind, but in this case, instead of an empty class, the variable contains null

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work because I inserted my control:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("index", "SchoolsInformation", FormMethod.Post))
                    {...}
```